# remove characters before renaming

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning python and also english. And I have a problem that might be easy, but I can't solve it. I have a folder of .txt's, I was able to extract by regular expression a sequence of numbers of each one.I need to rename each file with the sequence I extracted from .txt

```
import os
import re

path_txt = (r'C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\files')

name_files = os.listdir(path_txt)

for TXT in name_files:
    with open(path_txt + '\\' + TXT, "r") as content:
        search = re.search(r'(([0-9]{4})(/)(([1][9][0-9][0-9])|([2][0-9][0-9][0-9])))', content.read())
    if search is not None:
        os.rename(os.path.join(path_txt, TXT),
                  os.path.join("Processos3", search.group(0) + "_" + str(random.randint(100, 999)) + ".txt"))
```

some sequences have characters like "/", so when I use "rename" it returns an error because I can not rename files with this type of character. How do I delete the "/" before I rename the file?

ps: using python 3

Comment: why not using `replace("/","")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
search = search.replace("/", "")
```